# Have primary key both auto-generated and be able to set manually JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

I have a situation where I have two databases, stage and prod. And once a row has been pushed to stage and verified the entire row needs to be moved to prod, including the primary key of the row present in stage DB. So I want a way where if I pass the primary key as `null` the key is auto generated, else it is set to the value I have passed, so that when adding message to prod DB I can specify the same primary key as on the stage DB. Currently I am auto-generating the primary key for both tables, using this.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

I add a value to the database using

```
EntityManager em;
em.persist(message);
```

I am fairly new to JPA and Java Persistance, please let me know if it is somehow possible to achieve the above solution.

Comment: if the stage and prod where in sync they would have the same values. How are you migrating an "entire row" to production from staging?

Comment: So how I use my stage and prod DB is that I push a value on stage and then check if everything works fine, and then I push it to prod DB. Now I want to have a move to prod button for each row, on clicking which the same row shows up in the table of the prod DB(including the primary key).

Comment: push, like physically, metaphorically? Please be descriptive. Databases don't have buttons (only tuning knobs). Explain the SQL/code/process you have if any.

Comment: by push I mean add to the message table in the stage database, similarly for prod database. I have a UI Table which shows the messages in message table (Stage DB), and on selecting a row and pressing a "move to prod" button I want the same message to be replicated on the message table in the prod database. The issue is the primary key, currently the primary key is auto generated for both stage and prod DBs, and I want those IDs to be the same as well, but also want them to be auto generated for the stage DB and have the same schema for both the prod and stage DB.